# Can I decide whether to cache something based on inputs in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, caching

Suppose I am caching the response based on request parameters in Spring. 
Example : 
`@Cacheable(value = "personDetails", key = "#personId")
public PersonDetails getPersonDetails(String personId) {
  // Do something
}`

Now lets suppose someone can pass 'ALL' also as personId and I don't want to cache that. Could it be possible that I can decide at run time whether to cache this or not based on Input parameter passed. Please excuse with the example, but the usecase in same.

Thanks for the responses in advance :)

Comment: You are talking about server level cache. To implement server level cache you need some parameter and some value for it. So here you can consider 'ALL' as the value which tells client that the response which is there with you is not changed.So you can use 'ETag' class in Jax-rs or  spring to implement this feature.
Eg:@Cacheable(value="users", condition="#name.length < 32", unless="#result.hardback")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use `condition` attribute.

> Sometimes, a method might not be suitable for caching all the time (for example, it might depend on the given arguments). The cache annotations support such functionality through the `condition` parameter which takes a `SpEL` expression that is evaluated to either `true` or `false`.

For example:

```
@Cacheable(value = "personDetails", key = "#personId", condition="#personId != 'ALL'")
public PersonDetails getPersonDetails(String personId) {
  // Do something
}
```

More information you can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) under `Conditional caching` paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. Looks perfect and precise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query hints and add hints based on condition.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#d0e1215

You can use setHint like setParameter as below:

```
.setHint(“org.hibernate.cacheable”, false)
```